# What is a good API or way to create VMs programatically?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I'm working on a project where I think of distributing tasks to VMs that are dynamically managed (created, destroyed, paused, run processes from host, etc). I was wondering what would be a good approach or API to accomplish the management of the VMs. Below are some examples of what I'm thinking but I wanted to get some guidance on the best approach.

- [Vagrant-binding](https://github.com/guigarage/vagrant-binding): it looked perfect but it out of date and not supported.
- [Oracle Tools](https://github.com/coherence-community/oracle-tools): the vagrant module looks interesting but there isn't much documentation and I'm a bit confused on how to actually use it.
- [VirtualBox sdk](https://www.virtualbox.org/sdkref/): I'm a bit confused on the setup of this.

As you can see from the examples I was thinking in Java but I'm open to working on other languages. This project academic in nature and I'm a student so I know that this might not be the most practical thing to do but I wanted to see if it possible and what would be best way to accomplish it.

Comment: Have you taken a look at libvirt? http://libvirt.org/

Answer (score 0):

I have recently created a program to manage the VMs at my work. I used object-pascal (Delphi) to create the GUI and then did all the heavy lifting using vboxmanage commands that are ran as a process through cmd but called from my program. Oracle has a nice list of available commands [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html)

For example

List running Vms

```
VBoxManage.exe list runningvms
```

Import a VM

```
VBoxManage.exe import (VM_To_Import_Location) --vsys 0 --vmname (Name_of_VM)  --unit 11 --disk (Where_You_Want_VM_Stored)
```

Start a VM

```
VBoxManage.exe startvm (Name_Of_VM) --type headless
```

Take a Snapshot

```
VBoxManage.exe snapshot (VM_Name) take (Snapshot_Name) -desc "My Snapshot Description"
```

Restore a Snapshot

```
Vboxmanage.exe snapshot (VM_Name) restore (Snapshot_Name)
```

There are many more for pretty much everything you would want to do with a VM.